# Changing information displayed for Pay Later feature on contribution pages

Tags: contribution-page

Does anyone know where to go in Civicrm to change the I will send payment by check option on contribution pages?

I want to replace it with something like I will pay by cash or Bank Transfer

Comment: Please accept Pete's answer as correct (Click on the tick to the left of the answer.)  Stack exchange works best when the correct answers are indicated.

Answer (score 2):

It is on the Contribution Amounts tab for any Contribution Page eg http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/contribute/amount?reset=1&action=update&id=1.

Enable Pay Later and you will see

- Pay Later label
- Pay Later instructions

Comment: Thanks so much Petednz. Its so funny how things can be hiden  right under our noses.

Comment: can you pls keep SE happy then and accept the answer